# How to create a URLS with the question mark (?) In Django

Tags: django, parameters, django-urls

I create a URLS with the question mark (?) In Django.
The link does not work because the? is replaced by ca: ***% 3F***

here is the result of the url: / blog / Detail /% 3Ffollow_Jeudi = 2018-03-15.

I would like to get this: / blog / Detail /? Follow_Jeudi = 2018-03-15

How can I fix this problem.

Here is my view, the template and the url.

**My view:**

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
def DateAdd(request):
    if request.GET.get('date_create_schedule'):
        date_text = request.GET.get('date_create_schedule')
        newHistory = fdt_schedulejour(date=date_text,user_id=request.user.id)
        newHistory.save()
        results = 'test'
        title = '?follow_'
        jour_date = date_text

    return redirect('ajout_date', title,jour_date_text,jour_date)
```

**My template:**

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <form class="form-signin" id="login_form" method="get" action="/blog/DateAdd/">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="date_create_schedule"   value="{{ Activite_Date_click|date:"Y-m-d" }}"  >
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Get Data</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**My urls:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from blog import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('Detail/<str:title_p><str:jour_date_text><str:jour_date>', views.DateAdd.as_view(), name='ajout_date'),
]
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need that? Your URL would work fine without it.

Comment: BTW, it's called a `Query String`. It allows you to pass extra parameters to a URL. Example: `http://example.com/path/to/resource/?a=1&b=2`. From the looks of your urlconf, I don't think you need it.

Comment: This url: / blog / Detail /? Follow_Jeudi = 2018-03-15 is the result of a request.
The only thing that changes on this click url is: Thursday = 2018-03-15. So I have to keep this part there: / blog / Detail /? Follow_.
That's why I want to keep the (?). If I remove the (?), I get no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your URL for query string.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = (url(r'Detail/(?P<title>[-/\w]+)/(?P<jour_date_text>[-/\w]+)/(?P<jour_date>[-/\w]+)/$'),views.DateAdd.as_view(), name='ajout_date')
```

Hope so it will solve your problem

Comment: I use Django 2.0.2.
How I can change  URL for query string ?

Comment: you can use above mentioned urlpatter but url attribute is going to deprecate in future, so you can use re_path at the place of url. it will work.